# C# Resize DataGridView Column width

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to create a DataGridView in my C# Winforms appliation.

I'm adding entrys in the following way:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add("first", "second");

    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = table;
}
```

But I can't get the size of the datagrid to 100%.

Screenshot:

[image]

How could I make it fill the DataGrid?

Comment: Please accept one of answers if it solves your problem. Otherwise you can  write a comment to answer and describe why it doesn't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set columns Autosizemode property to fill

```
            table.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

            table.Rows.Add("first", "second");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Look - [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode(v=vs.110).aspx)